# iOS Swift Crash : *** -[MyApp.SharedData retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15d3c6fd0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory, crash

I am getting the following error, but I have no idea why this occurring. 
This is happening with my Swift class that I created. I don't know the appropriate way to fix this. Here is my SharedData Code. Here is some of my SharedData code. Not all the code is showing, but if I comment out the other methods the problem still occurs.

```
 var databaseManager : DatabaseManager?
 var user : User?

    required override init()
    {
        super.init()

        self.initSharedData()

    }
    class func sharedData() -> SharedData {

        struct Singleton {

            static let instance = SharedData()

        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }

    func initSharedData(){

        self.databaseManager = DatabaseManager()
        self.user = self.databaseManager?.userInfo

    }
```

Comment: Don't use `self.initSharedData` in init, rather call `instance.initSharedData` inside your `struct Singleton`